# Java: Try to Understand Getting Inputs from Users Using Scanner

Tags: java

I have this programs and a few questions regarding to how .next(), .nextInt(), .hasNext() and .hasNextInt() of Scanner class work. Thank you in advance for any of your help :)

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class test {

    public static void main (String[] args) {
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    int age;
    System.out.print("Please enter your age: ");
    while (!console.hasNextInt()) {
            System.out.print("Please re-enter your age: ");
            console.next();
        }
    age = console.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Your age is "+age);
    }  
}
```

1/ When **!console.hasNextInt()** is executed for the first time, why does it ask for an input?

I thought at first the **console** is empty, so **!console.hasNextInt()** is True (empty is not an int), then it should go directly from **"Please enter your age: "** to **"Please re-enter your age: "** but my thought seems to be wrong.

Here, the user needs to enter something before **"Please re-enter your age: "** is printed.

2/ The data type of **console.next()** is always a String (I tried making **int s = console.next();** and it gave an error), then why isn't this a infinite loop?

3/ For an instance, when it comes to **console.next();**, I input **21**. Why does **age** have the value of **21**? I thought because of **console.hasNextInt()**, I need to enter another number, and that new number will be the value of age.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`hasNextInt()` waits for an input string and then tells you if can be converted to an `int`. With that in mind, let's go over your questions:

> When `!console.hasNextInt()` is executed for the first time, why does it ask for an input?

Because it blocks until there's some input from the console.

> The data type of `console.next()` is always a String (I tried making `int s = console.next();` and it gave an error), then why isn't this a infinite loop?

Because `hasNextInt()` returns true when the input can be *converted* to an `int`, for example `"21"`.

> For an instance, when it comes to `console.next();`, I input `21`. Why does `age` have the value of `21`? I thought because of `console.hasNextInt()`, I need to enter another number, and that new number will be the value of `age`.

Calling `next()` doesn't wait for a *new* input, it just swallows the input that was tested by `hasNextInt()` so the scanner can move on to the next one. It could have been the first statement in the loop, with the same effect.

Answer (score 1):

> The java.util.Scanner.hasNextInt() method returns true if the next
>   token in this scanner's input can be interpreted as an int value in
>   the default radix using the nextInt() method.

When you start with a non integer input, hasNextInt() will be false and you will enter while loop. Then it will prompt you to re-enter your age. But if you start with integer, you won't enter the loop. Your age will be printed.

`console.next()` means it takes next input token and returns String. If you write down your code as:

```
String s = null;
while (!console.hasNextInt()) {
    s = console.next();
    System.out.println("You entered an invalid input: " + s);
    System.out.print("Please re-enter your age: ");

}
```

`console.next()` is being used for handling the non-integer inputs. Now, if you enter a non-integer input `twenty`, you'll see that `console.hasNextInt()` will be false and `console.next()` will read it.